# Check @media rule with javascript by detecting css rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I know about matchMedia.js but I was thinking I could detect the current @media rule with something as easy as this. However, it's not working in firefox – (which usually means it's not correct in the first place...) Looking at it now, shouldn't the content be on an `:after` pseudo element? Any advice? I have a [CodePen HERE:](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/cdxvH)

### CSS

```
#test {
  content:  "small"
}

@media only screen and (min-width: $bp1) {
  #test {
    content: "medium"
  }
}
```

### jQuery

```
var sizeCheck = function() {
  
  if ( $("#test").css('content') === 'small') {
    
    $('.proof').text('jQuery knows this page is SMALL from reading the CSS @media rules.');

  } else if ( $("#test").css('content') === 'medium') {
    
    $('.proof').text('jQuery knows this page is MEDIUM from reading the CSS @media rules.');

  }
    
};

// run the function on document ready
$(document).ready(sizeCheck);

// AND run the function on window resize event
$(window).resize(sizeCheck);
```

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://css-tricks.com/media-query-change-detection-in-javascript-through-css-animations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got quite an interesting test there!

To answer your question: yes, `content` can only be used with `:after` and `:before` pseudo classes.

> Applies to ::before and ::after pseudo-elements

Source: [content - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)

#### EDIT #1

I found something for you; looks like it is possible to get the `content` of `:after` 'after all' :)

```
var content = window.getComputedStyle(
    document.querySelector('#test'), ':after'
).getPropertyValue('content');
```

Source: [Get Pseudo-Element Properties with JavaScript](http://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element)

I'm not used to CodePen, so created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yGNZ/5/).

#### EDIT #2

Looks like FireFox adds a double code to the actual value, so in the console it appeared like this: `""string""`.

A way around this could be to test against both like this:

```
if (content == '"small"' || content == 'small') {
    // ...
}
```

I updated [the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5yGNZ/8/).

Comment: Well, that adds `:after` but the jQuery isn't actually seeing it because it can't check after. I wonder is there is a property like content that can be descriptive AND be read by both. Otherwise I'll have to use `display:none` or something to detect.

Comment: Looks great, but still no dice in FireFox. Mysterious.

Comment: interesting, 'cause when i `console.log(content)` the value of `content` is there, but for some reason it's enclosed in two double quotes, like this: `""medium""` - have you seen that?

Comment: well, found a way around it (see my edit #2 above)... not sure if it's the perfect solution, but it definitely is one ;)

Comment: Hmmm. Great. I'll check back in after my day. I wonder if it makes a difference if you use single `'quotes'` in the CSS.

Comment: nope, tried that too... but my workaround should do the job, at least for me it worked on chrome and ff too...